# Get all urls from a website using python

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, urllib2, web-crawler

I am learning to build web crawlers and currently working on getting all urls from a site. I have been playing around and don't have the same code as I did before but I have been able to get all the links but my issues is the recursion I need to do the same things over and over but what I think my issue is the recursion what it is doing is right for the code I have written. My code is bellow

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import urllib2
import urlparse
from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup

def getAllUrl(url):
    page = urllib2.urlopen( url ).read()
    urlList = []
    try:
        soup = BeautifulSoup(page)
        soup.prettify()
        for anchor in soup.findAll('a', href=True):
            if not 'http://' in anchor['href']:
                if urlparse.urljoin('http://bobthemac.com', anchor['href']) not in urlList:
                    urlList.append(urlparse.urljoin('http://bobthemac.com', anchor['href']))
            else:
                if anchor['href'] not in urlList:
                    urlList.append(anchor['href'])

        length = len(urlList)

        for url in urlList:
            getAllUrl(url)

        return urlList
    except urllib2.HTTPError, e:
        print e

if __name__ == "__main__":
    urls = getAllUrl('http://bobthemac.com')
    for x in urls:
        print x
```

What I am trying to achieve is get all the urls for a site with the current set-up the program runs till it runs out of memory all I want is to get the urls from a site. Does anyone have any idea on how to do this think I have the right idea just need some small changes to the code.

**EDIT**

For those of you what are intrested bellow is my working code that gets all the urs for the site someone might find it useful. It's not the best code and does need some work but with some work it could be quite good.

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import urllib2
import urlparse
from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup

def getAllUrl(url):
urlList = []
try:
    page = urllib2.urlopen( url ).read()
    soup = BeautifulSoup(page)
    soup.prettify()
    for anchor in soup.findAll('a', href=True):
        if not 'http://' in anchor['href']:
            if urlparse.urljoin('http://bobthemac.com', anchor['href']) not in urlList:
                urlList.append(urlparse.urljoin('http://bobthemac.com', anchor['href']))
        else:
            if anchor['href'] not in urlList:
                urlList.append(anchor['href'])

    return urlList

except urllib2.HTTPError, e:
    urlList.append( e )

if __name__ == "__main__":
urls = getAllUrl('http://bobthemac.com')

fullList = []

for x in urls:
    listUrls = list
    listUrls = getAllUrl(x)
    try:
        for i in listUrls:
            if not i in fullList:
                fullList.append(i)
    except TypeError, e:
        print 'Woops wrong content passed'

for i in fullList:
    print i
```

Comment: Looks like your function does not return anything.

Comment: Yeah it's a work in progress the ´print urlList´ is where the return would be I am just trying to play about with it. Edited to show what it was like with a return.

Comment: Hate it when people give negative mark an no reason

Comment: You create a recursion and never break it, I think it's that make you program never ended util out of memory.

Comment: I know this I mentioned this in my post I am looking to see if the method I am using is correct and how to break it out.

Comment: Have a look at http://scrapy.org/.

Comment: Looked at scrappy not really what I need for this project as this is the smallest part and scrapy would make it even bigger. There is a whole AI system behind this that is massive.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In you function `getAllUrl`, you call `getAllUrl` again in a `for` loop, it makes a recursion.

Elements will never be moved out once put into `urlList`, so `urlList` will never be empty,  and then, the recursion will never break up.

That's why your program will never end up util out of memory.

Comment: I know this I under stand this I might not have explained what I need I am looking to do some recursion.

Comment: I cannot explain it in a few words, but I wrote a lib for similar job (crawl links recursively) beforce, here is a link: https://github.com/zhaoqifa/scod/blob/master/lib/utils.py. Get start with the `crawl_links` function.

Comment: Thanks managed to get it sorted in the end the function you pointed me to helped me out but probably not how you would think. Some small tweaks got me the right code that works quite well. It could be faster I will post above.

Answer (score 2):

I think this works:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import urllib2
import urlparse
from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup

def getAllUrl(url):
    try:
        page = urllib2.urlopen( url ).read()
    except:
        return []
    urlList = []
    try:
        soup = BeautifulSoup(page)
        soup.prettify()
        for anchor in soup.findAll('a', href=True):
            if not 'http://' in anchor['href']:
                if urlparse.urljoin(url, anchor['href']) not in urlList:
                    urlList.append(urlparse.urljoin(url, anchor['href']))
            else:
                if anchor['href'] not in urlList:
                    urlList.append(anchor['href'])

        length = len(urlList)

        return urlList
    except urllib2.HTTPError, e:
        print e

def listAllUrl(urls):
    for x in urls:
        print x
        urls.remove(x)
        urls_tmp = getAllUrl(x)
        for y in urls_tmp:
            urls.append(y)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    urls = ['http://bobthemac.com']
    while(urls.count>0):
        urls = getAllUrl('http://bobthemac.com')
        listAllUrl(urls)
```

Comment: This does the same thing I have just done finds the links on the page then repeats them over and over.

Comment: I've edited the code with a line urls.remove(x) after print(x) so that the memory is not waisted even though recursion is done. You can check the difference by adding print len(urls) with the line urls.remove(x) commented and uncommented.